# Move element before second to last h2 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to move an elmement with class `.books_inarticle_list` from its native possition tu just before the second to last H2.

I am using the following which is not working:

```
$('.books_inarticle_list').insertBefore('#content_column > h2:nth-last-child(2)');
```

On the other hand something like this works:

```
$('.books_inarticle_list').insertBefore('#content_column > h2:nth-of-type(6)');
```

So the issue must be with the `nth-last-child()` selector, but I don't see what it might be.

Does anyone see anything wrong with that code or knows an alternative way to move that element to just before the second to last H2 tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`.get()` method](https://api.jquery.com/get/), which supports negative numbers to go in reverse.

```
$('.books_inarticle_list').insertBefore($('#content_column > h2').get(-2));
```

**Edit** On second thought, it makes more sense to follow your own examples and use the [`:nth-last-of-type()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-of-type-selector/), which will go in reverse.

```
$('.books_inarticle_list').insertBefore('#content_column > h2:nth-last-of-type(2)');
```

The reason `:nth-last-child()` isn't working for you is because that, and `:nth-child()`, refers to the number of siblings they have in the DOM, not the list of elements returned by the selector.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to use ":eq" even  ":nth-of-type". So will be :

```
$('.books_inarticle_list').insertBefore('#content_column > h2:eq('+($('#content_column > h2').length()-2)+')');
```

Comment: I need to move the element to just before the second to last H2 without knowing how many H2 tags there might be in the page. The nth-of-type(6) was just an example to ilustrate my trial and error process and why I believe the problem is with the css selector and not other parts of the code

Comment: this is how to select the element at 2th position

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off providing your HTML for the optimal solution, however given your question I'd suggest something like the following:

```
var $h2s = $("#content_column > h2");
var $secondToLast = $h2s.eq($h2s.length-2);
$('.books_inarticle_list').insertBefore($secondToLast);
```

I passed on using `nth-child` just because that will be thrown off any time you modify your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Note, `:nth-*` selectors use 1-based indexing. You can use `:nth-last-of-type()` selector with `2` as parameter to selector second from last element of that type, chain `.before()` with `$(".books_article_list")` as parameter.

```js
$("#content_column h2:nth-last-of-type(2)").before($(".books_article_list"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="books_article_list">books</div>
<div id="content_column">
<h2>0</h2>
<h2>1</h2>
<h2>2</h2>
<h2>3</h2>
<h2>4</h2>
<h2>5</h2>
<h2>6</h2>
</div>
```